# BackboneJS .fetch() put one object from response in collection

Tags: backbone.js, response, fetch

My server response is having two objects (picture):
[image]

How can i put just secound object members (models) in my Backbone Collection. I am using collection.fetch to get data from server. Can I somehowe addapt my server response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the parse method of your collection:

```
var coll = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 parse: function(data){
  return data.statuses;
 }
});
```

Your Collection will contain what you return from your parse function, in this case you reduce it to the statuses array from your server response.

Answer (score 2):

use parse()

see:
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

in your collection:

```
yourCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  //other collection stuff.

  parse: function(response) {
    //save the search metadata in case you need it later
    this.search_meatadata = response["search_metadata"];
    // return the array of objects.
    return response["statuses"];
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, homtg was first but both answers are right.